# Check if a NSString is empty or only contains whitespace or tabs?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm currently using `isEqualToString:@""` and it works fine when the textField does have nothing. However, it does not catch the case when the input has only white spaces or tabs. What should I do to make it smarter so that input such as `"    "` will not be allowed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmedString = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
if ([trimmedString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // it's empty or contains only white spaces
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length > 0
```

Use this to test if the string contains characters other than whitespace.